# How to access a document.doc and .txt modify the content using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to access the .doc files and update in that document using javascript .

Thanks

Comment: you should probably put a little more effort into your question if you expect than anyone should 1) understand what you want and 2) put any effort into answering you. just sayin..

Comment: sadly no, the .doc and the javascript don't get along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this, for one `.doc` isn't stored in a format JavaScript can easily interpret...and I'm unaware of anyone ever taking the effort to port the `.doc` format to JavaScript.  If it was possible, the library would need to edit it in memory and upload it again in some other format, base64 encoded perhaps?

In any case this is no small project, it's a *huge* effort and I've never seen anything close.  That being said, there are alternatives depending on your exact needs, for example these guys do a browser implementation: http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/products/dotnet/overview/

I'm not sure if there are others, and I haven't personally used theirs, but maybe that'll put you on the right track to finding the client solution you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to do this with ActiveX objects in IE. Probably still can. Code looked something like this:

```
var word = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
word.Visible = true;
// ...
```

See the reference for  [word's object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we(VS.80).aspx).